# ImageMagick: write pixels in BGR order

Tags: imagemagick

I want to convert (a lot of) JPEG images to the Sun Raster format (see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/format/sunraster/egff.htm) for instance), because my program can only use this format.

The issue is that my program only allows images of type Old
or Standard i.e. with pixel written in the BGR order. (I should change that but don't have the time).
By default, ImageMagick generates files in the RGB format.

I have found a [trick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18202) to swap the color planes, but as the file is style written as RGB I get fancy colors.

This is probably a simple option to pass to ImageMagick, but I didn't find it.
Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 10):

Another way to swap colors is to use the `-color-matrix` option. For example, to convert RGB to BGR:

```
convert input.png -color-matrix '0 0 1
                                 0 1 0
                                 1 0 0' output.png
```

Reference: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/

Answer (score 6):

In Imagemagick 6, you can do that easily with -swap command. Lets swap the red and blue channels in the logo image.

[image]

```
convert logo.png -separate +channel \
-swap 0,2 -combine -colorspace sRGB logo_bgr.png
```

[image]

For very old versions of Imagemagick use RGB rather than sRGB.

In Imagemagick 7, use magick rather than convert.

Answer (score 3):

I have an idea how to swap Red and Blue colors in RGB image:

```
convert ( image_RGB.bmp -channel B -separate ) \
    ( image_RGB.bmp -channel G -separate ) \
    ( image_RGB.bmp -channel R -separate ) -channel RGB -combine image_BGR.bmp
```

You just cut channels form original image and write them in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your example but it doesn't work. Are you sure of the syntax?

Comment: In any case, this sounds like  [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18202) i.e. you swap the channels. But in this case the colors will be different. In my was it's simply a matter of image format.

Comment: The syntax: try to remove "\" symbols and breaklines, I added it for readability. Yes, the channels are just swapped and when you view converted image in standart viewer, color seems fancy. But I thought your program reads and views it correctly, so why do you need something else?

Comment: (sorry I was away for a few days) My program tests the type field in the header. If the value is different than Old or Standard it stops. I could fix that but that would be a bad hack.

Comment: BTW nautilus thumbnailer (under GNOME desktop) seems to be unable to display RGB images converted with image magick.

Comment: Man, I give up. The only way I see is to edit ImageMagick and add your own option (since it is opensource).

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that in Imagemagick

```
convert image.jpg image.sun
```

or

```
convert image.jpg SUN:image.sun
```

would convert to BGR format if that is the standard for the sun raster format. See imagemagick.org/script/formats.php.

Have you tried that?

If that does not work, then use my -swap command but write to .sun file format rather than png, which I used above. That is

```
convert logo.png -separate +channel -swap 0,2 -combine -colorspace sRGB logo_bgr.sun
```